# Using Regex Wildcards before a string that doesn't include the string

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a key term from a sentence that can start with a word or set of specific words and can be followed by random words until the key term.  The extraction is done with a Named Group.

```
(?<QUALIFY>Anchor[^.]{1,30})(?<CAPTURE>(?<OPTIONAL>(Up |Down |Left |Right))?(?<!\d)(\d{1,5})( Keyword1| Keyword2| Keyword3))
```

This works if the string is

- Anchor 33 Keyword1

which returns

- QUALIFY: Anchor
- CAPTURE: 33 Keyword1

However if the string is

- Anchor Up 33 Keyword1

which includes one of the optional words in the key term I am trying to capture it returns:

- QUALIFY: Anchor Up
- CAPTURE: 33 Keyword1

Clearly it thinks 'Up' is part of the wildcard string.

I was expecting/desiring:

- QUALIFY: Anchor
- CAPTURE: Up 33 Keyword1

So the question is how can I force the regex to not consider anything in my keyterm as part of the wildcard "QUALIFY"? I've tried various ^ and ?! to no avail.

Comment: There is an extra P before capture and an extra space in righ t. I am not sure if this is related to ur question

Comment: I thought that the P was a requirement in named groups, I removed and it worked fine so it looks like I was misinformed on that thanks that will help moving forward. Fixed the 'Righ t' as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to make your Qualify group lazy:

```
(?<QUALIFY>Anchor[^.]{1,30}?)(?P<CAPTURE>(?<OPTIONAL>(Up |Down |Left |Righ t))?(?<!\d)(\d{1,5})( Keyword1| Keyword2| Keyword3))
```

Comment: That worked, interesting. I thought the ? was just a qualifier as in the qualify group is optional. For instance I used that in OPTIONAL group since they don't need to be part of the capture string.

Comment: @user3649739 Indeed. The ? operator could mean optional if it is used in let's say ab(cd)?. here cd is optional. But when it follows another operator like *? or +?, it makes them lazy. You might want to read on possessives as well *+ and ++.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy modifier in the first group:

```
(?<QUALIFY>Anchor[^.]{1,30}?)
#                   here __^
```

Also I guess `(Up |Down |Left |Righ t)` is really `(Up |Down |Left |Right )`